# How to place a form on the homepage of a CakePHP application?

Tags: php, view, controller, indexing, cakephp-1.3

Just begun developing CakePHP. The homepage of my application is meant to have a form, this form has a corresponding model and controller.

Where do I place the view code for this form in order for it to appear on the application homepage and call the correct controller action when submitted?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normally located in the `app/views/pages/` directory. The pages view/controller is used primarily to serve static content. However, you can easily change the code used to render the home page by modifying `app/config/routes.php` and adding a line similar to:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'your_cont', 'action' => 'your_action'));
```

For more info, you can check out:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/958/The-Pages-Controller

http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration